# Momentjs how to get next month last date

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

i am trying to get the last date of the next month, for some reason momentjs returns the wrong date

For Example :

```
console.log(moment('02/28/2018', "MM/DD/YYYY").add(i, 'M'));
```

returns :

```
moment("2018-03-28T00:00:00.000")
```

where the right date should be :

```
moment("2018-03-31T00:00:00.000")
```

Comment: a) get todays date. b) set date to 1. c) add 2 months ... d) subtract 1 day

Comment: adding 1 month to the 'n'th day of 'm' will result in the 'n'th day of 'm+1' - so, how is that **wrong**?

Comment: @JaromandaX—you don't need to set the date first, month and date can be in one go, e.g. in POJS you can do: `var d = new Date(2017,11,31);
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 2, 0);` returns 31 Jan. Adding 2 months doesn't roll over an extra month by adding the months first then the date, both month and date are set at the same time. ;-)

Comment: I never knew that about setMonth! learn something every day

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`.add()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) you are just adding a month to your actual date but you want also go to last day of this month, and for this you can use [`.endOf()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/):

```
moment('02/28/2018', "MM/DD/YYYY").add(1, 'M').endOf("month")
// 2018-03-31T23:59:59.999Z
```

Comment: For anyone wondering: This solution is also safe if the next month has less days than the current. So `moment('01/31/2018').add(1, 'M')` results in `2018-02-28T23:59:59.999Z`

Answer (score 0):

You are adding 1 month to 2/28, so you get 3/28.  It only increases the month part.

To get the last day of the month, you can use:

```js
// Should be 12/31/2018 23:59:59
console.log(moment("2018-12-01").endOf("month").toString());

// Should be last day, hour, minute, and second of the current month
console.log(moment().endOf("month").toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation of [guijob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49122718/5326920), if you want to get based on current day you can use

```
moment().add(1, "month").endOf("month")
```